# Non-greedy regex does not pick the closest choice

Tags: regex

My regex does not pick the closest 'cont' pair to the inner text. How can I fix that?

Input:

```
cont cont ItextI /cont /cont
```

Regex:

```
cont.*?I(.*?)I.*?/cont
```

Match:

```
cont cont ItextI /cont
```

Match I need:

```
cont ItextI /cont
```

Comment: Compulsory link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
cont(?:(?!/?cont).)*I(.*?)I(?:(?!/?cont).)*/cont
```

will only match the innermost block.

**Explanation:**

```
cont        # match "cont"
(?:         # Match...
 (?!/?cont) # (as long as we're not at the start of "cont" or "/cont")
 .          # any character.
)*          # Repeat any number of times.
I           # Match "I"
(.*?)       # Match as few characters as possible, capturing them.
I           # Match "I"
(?:         # Same as above
 (?!/?cont)
 .
)*
/cont       # Match "/cont"
```

This explicitly forbids `cont` or `/cont` to appear between the opening `cont` and the to-be-captured text (and between that text and the closing `/cont`).

Comment: thanks! what is the name of these constructs you used? I used (?<=cont).*?I(.*?)I.*?/cont this works too.

Comment: `(?!...`)` is a negative [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Answer (score 2):

The reason you match on `cont cont ItextI /cont` is that the regex matches the first part of your pattern `cont` on the first "cont", then it uses the reluctant `.*?` to gobble up the whitespace, next cont and whitespace preceding `ItextI`. When it reached `ItextI`, it recognizes the `I` as matching the next part of the pattern, and continues with the rest of the regex. As minitech writes, this is because the regex is working from the beginning of the string and finding the earliest possible match.

If you can make assumptions about the whitespace, you can write:

```
cont\s+I(.*?)I\s+/cont
```

This will match in your example above.

Comment: no, there can be anything, not only whitespaces

After some research in look-behind regex feature I found the solution:

    (?<=cont).*?I(.*?)I.*?/cont

Works well in AS and Java

Comment: Okay, it would be helpful if you provided a more complete example in the future, as the input text above is a bit misleading.